# User does not have privileges for ALTERTABLE_ADDCOLS while using spark.sql to read the data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Select query in spark.sql is resulting in the following error:

`User *username* does not have privileges for ALTERTABLE_ADDCOLS`

Spark version - `2.1.0`

Trying to execute the following query:

```
dig = spark.sql("""select col1, col2 from dbname.tablename""")
```

Comment: The sql you provided is not valid. Do you mean and acutally execute `dig = spark.sql("""select col1, col2 from dbname.tablename""")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by the `spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode` propertie.
By default, spark tries to infer the table's schema and then change its properties.

To avoid these messages you can alter the default configuration to `INFER_ONLY`.
Considering a spark session named `spark`, the code below should work:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode", "INFER_ONLY")
```